# MySQL update with data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with the two tables that I need modified. 
The first table holds notes

```
id type note
1  1    24 months warranty
2  1    12 months warranty
3  2    Garage in Denver
4  3    Pre sales maintenance done
....
```

And then a vehicle table that holds many vehicle tables and a field that hold notes with their text instead of a pointer

```
id licence_plate  ... sales_notes ...
1  XH34DN         ... <warranty>24 months warranty</warranty><garage>Garage in Denver</garage><maintenance>Pre sales maintenance done</maintenance> ...
2  K4B3C6         ... <warranty>12 months warranty</warranty><garage>Garage in Sacramento</garage><maintenance>Pre sales maintenance not done</maintenance> ...
```

As you can imagine this is higly inneficient and I want to modify to pointers that hold the id of the note.

```
id licence_plate  ... warranty_note garage_note maintenace_note ...
1  XH34DN         ... 1             3           4 ...
2  K4B3C6         ... 2             7           12 ...
```

I can do it manual updates but I would like to build one that makes it automatically by type.

So for notes.type=1 if the notes.note text is found in vehicle.sales_notes it updates the vehicle.warranty_note.

Any idea how to build something like that?

I have something like this in mind, but id doesn't work. No results are updated

```
UPDATE tx_vehicle v, tx_note n
SET v.garage_note = n.uid
WHERE v.sales_notes LIKE ('%'+n.note+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has special [XML parsing functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue).

```
insert into your_new_notes_table (id, licence_plate, warranty_note, garage_note, maintenace_note)
select
    sn.id,
    sn.license_plate,
    (select nt.id from notes as nt where nt.type = 1 and nt.note = ExtractValue(sn.sales_note, "/warranty")) as warranty_note,
    (select nt.id from notes as nt where nt.type = 1 and nt.note = ExtractValue(sn.sales_note, "/garage")) as garage_note,
    (select nt.id from notes as nt where nt.type = 1 and nt.note = ExtractValue(sn.sales_note, "/maintenance")) as maintenance_note
from note_types as nt
```

Although, it will fail if exact note from sales is not found in `note_types` table. You can adjust note text comparison, replacing it with like operator, regex checking or another functions; you can replace abbreviations with full words or invent your own MySQL function. Moreover, you can invent your own MySQL function that would encompass internal `select`s and return `null` if note is not found in `note_types` table.

If you want to update existing table, you need to perform `update` query with `join` to same `select` as I provided.

Comment: thanks George, but the sales_notes values are similar to those, not the same, so XML parsing won't detect them.
And I am not trying you insert in the note table, I want to modify the structure of the vehicle table.

Comment: @Niall I added some notes to my answer. Exact solution depends on how they're similar. Letters case, spaces can be handled easily. Common abbreviations, mistypes and simple synonyms are doable too via replacements table. Possibly, it's easier to tackle it using programming language.